# How to use the lodash _groupBy

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, lodash

This is how my json looks like:

```js
invoices = {
  "count": 1 "data": Array(0)[{
    "company": "ABC PLC",
    "customer": {
      "name": "XYZ"
    },
    "invoiceFees": Array(2)[
      0: {
        "quarter": {
          "q_name": "A",
          "description": "payments for quarter A"
        }
      },
      1: {
        "quarter": {
          "q_name": "B",
          "description": "payments for quarter B"
        }
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

I am trying to group invoice results by Quarter. This is how I am doing it:

```
console.log(_.groupBy(invoices.data.invoiceFees, 'quarter.q_name'));
```

This slices everything down to an empty result like this:

```
invoices = {}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

My desired output sould be something of this sort:

```js
invoices = {
"data": [{
  "company": "ABC PLC",
  "customer": {
    "name": "XYZ"
  },
  "invoiceFees": [{
      "quarter A:  {
      "description": "payments for quarter A"
    },
    "quarter B:  {
    "description": "payments for quarter B"
  }
}]
}]
}
```

Comment: Can you please show your desired output?

Comment: I guess the second arg should be `'quarter.q_name'`

Comment: The json doesn't look like valid.

Comment: @NickParsons I have added the desired output but is open to any output that could just help me group the invoiceFees

Comment: @ntalbs sure, i have just tried to come up with a dummy json data

Comment: @georg sorry, actually that's what i had that wasn't working, have edited the post to capture it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, for your specific example, the following produces the result you're after:

```
invoices = {
    data: _.map(invoices.data, d => _.assign(
        _.omit(d, 'invoiceFees'),
        _.fromPairs(
            _.map(d.invoiceFees, f => [
                'quarter ' + f.quarter.q_name,
                _.omit(f.quarter, 'q_name')
            ])
        )
    ))
}
```

if you need `invoiceFees` as a separate object, then

```
invoices = {
    data: _.map(invoices.data, d => _.assign(
        d,
        {invoiceFees: _.fromPairs(
            _.map(d.invoiceFees, f => [
                'quarter ' + f.quarter.q_name,
                _.omit(f.quarter, 'q_name')
            ])
        )}
    ))
}
```

Comment: yes it did group the quarters, but it should have retained quarters inside the invoiceFees[ ]

Comment: @Emmon: please do not edit your questions in a way that invalidates existing answers. This produces exactly the output you've asked for in the previous revision.

Comment: sorry @georg, i put the wrong expected result. I will be careful not to cause such in the future. But yes your answer did produce the result as to what I previously asked before the revision. is there  a way i can manipulate it to include the revised result?